# Download PDFs : Remote end closed connection without response

Tags: python, urllib

I want to gather the text from thousands PDF files with Python. The text extraction from PDFs is working fine but my code is stopping randomly (doesn't stop at the same PDF each time) during the execution with this error :

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

I'm using urllib. I want to know how can I avoid this error and if I can't how to catch it (even `except:` does not work)

The code I used :

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=";", error_bad_lines=False)

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['year'], "- adding ",row['title'])
    request.urlretrieve(row['pdfarticle'],"_tmp.pdf")
    try:
        row['fullarticle'] = convert_pdf_to_txt("_tmp.pdf")
    except TypeError:
        row['fullarticle'] = ""
        pass

os.remove("_tmp.pdf")
print("Done. Saving csv...")
df.to_csv("my_structured_articles.csv")
print("Done. Head(10) : ")
print(df.head(10))
return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the try except block here -

```py
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['year'], "- adding ",row['title'])
    try:
        request.urlretrieve(row['pdfarticle'],"_tmp.pdf")
    except http.client.RemoteDisconnected:
        continue # this will skip the url throwing error
```

You can find the documentation for the exception [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.RemoteDisconnected).

Comment: Oh... I should have slept a little more. I will try that after work

Comment: Solved this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should put `request.urlretrieve(row['pdfarticle'],"_tmp.pdf")` under try catch block.

Secondly, if the problem is only because of networking. You should use retry a several times. Something like this:

```
retry = MAX_TRIES
while retry != 0:
  try:
    request.urlretrieve(row['pdfarticle'],"_tmp.pdf")
    break
  except http.client.RemoteDisconnected:
    retry -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Gonna try it later

Comment: The last except block is worse than useless - in python3 it will make the traceback more confuse, and in Python2 you will actually just plain loose the original traceback.

Comment: You may still want to reraise the exception if the operation still fails after MAX_TRIES rounds. Hint: to reraise the current exception without loosing the traceback, use the `raise` statement _without_ arguments.

Comment: nice idea. but I think that till depends on how he wants to use the script, maybe he just want to skip if it's not working?